# JAXB development methodology

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am working with JAXB to parse XML derived from a schema. JAXB generated about 500 classes to parse everything that can be in the XML and my goal is to take the XML data to create objects from another library to be displayed on a map. What is the best way to go about this translation? I have been creating secondary objects to facilitate this i.e. JAXB objects -> MyObject -> MapObject. But is MyObject needed? I want to insulate my code as much as possible from schema changes that cause me to regenerate JAXB objects, but I am also just about creating a new MyObject for each and every JAXB object. The alternative I see is just modify the JAXB objects with the JAXB annotations to meet my needs i.e. JAXB objects -> MapObject.